# Android notifications when app is in background

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending push notification from google firebase for my android app with target of Android 5.0:

My push notification code is:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    String badge = "0";
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(
            getString(R.string.app_host_name)
    );

    Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
    if (data.size() > 0) {
        try {
            uri = Uri.parse(
                    data.get("link")
            );

            badge = data.get("badge");
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            //
        }
    }

    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
        sendNotification(notification.getTitle(), notification.getBody(), uri.toString(), badge);
    }
}



private void sendNotification(String title, String body, String url, String badge) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    if (Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches()) {
        intent.putExtra("link", url);
    }

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0,
            intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
    );

    Resources resources = getApplicationContext().getResources();

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "default")
                    .setColor(
                            resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark)
                    )
                    .setSmallIcon(
                            R.drawable.ic_stat_icon
                    )
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(body)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setNumber(Integer.parseInt(badge))
                    .setLargeIcon(
                            BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                                    resources,
                                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher
                            )
                    )
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                "default",
                "Main notification channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        );

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(
                notificationChannel
        );
    }

    notificationManager.notify(
            1,
            notificationBuilder.build()
    );
}
```

And everything is super perfect when application is active/opened/not in background, but when it is not, notifications are not grouped, there is no number displayed, and no reaction on all of this settings at all, what i was able to change is only small icon and circle color via manifest settings

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_stat_icon" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
```

but why? It's like when app is in background notifications are not using settings from Activity code but using only some kind of "default" one from AndroidManifest.

Comment: you can use transparent icon for notification.

Comment: Yep, i know but problem is not an icon, problem is different options at all when app is on background, app isn't taking *setNumber*, *setAutoCancel*, *setSmallIcon*, *setLargeIcon* options, nothing what is not defined in manifest

Answer (score 3):

As you said in the comments:

> *when app is on background, app isn't taking setNumber, setAutoCancel, setSmallIcon, setLargeIcon options*

It is because you are using notification payload to send the notification which only triggers on the foreground.

So when your app is in the background it does not enter this method.

to solve this you can use `data` payload alone:

```
"data": {
"titles": "New Title",
"bodys": "body here"
}
```

since the data payload will enter the [`onMessageReceived()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) when your app is in foreground/background.

then in fcm you can do this:

```
  if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {

        title = remoteMessage.getData().get("titles");
        body = remoteMessage.getData().get("bodys");
    }
```

Comment: Updated my starting post, i am already doing this and this doesn't work, it have no effect on notification icons for example

Comment: the title and body seems to be notification payload, this `notification.getTitle(), notification.getBody()`

Comment: It turned out i was sending notification message with data payload instead of data message (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notification-messages-with-optional-data-payload)

Comment: @MyMomSaysIamSpecial please mark this as solved..if provided solution has resolved issue.. or kindly update it with the solution you have found if any..

Comment: @PeterHaddad nope.. :(

Comment: @MuahmmadTayyib did u use data payload for background?

Comment: @PeterHaddad yes , only the data payload object not the default notification object..
but facing issues like 2 notifications are created one a default by the sysytem and other created by me. I'm unable to delete the default one..

Comment: So it's working... @MuahmmadTayyib that issue is probably from the service java file not the cloud functions